# Consistency order of backward Euler method

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

How can I proof that *backward Euler method has consistency order 1*?

Implicit function theorem states that for a sufficiently small $h$,
$$
 \vec{y}_1 = \vec{y}_0 + h f(t_1,\vec{y}_1)
$$
has a unique solution. Then, Taylor expansion of exact solution is
$$
\vec{y}(t_0+h) = \vec{y}_0 + h f(t_0,\vec{y}_0) + O(h^2).
$$
I only need Taylor expansion of approximate solution to proof that backward Euler method has consistency order 1, right? How I obtain such Taylor expansion? I have to consider $\vec{y}_1 = \vec{y}_1(t_0+h)$?

Comment: Just apply the definition of consistency.

Comment: @Yimin Yes, but I can't find the Taylor expansion of approximate solution $\vec{y}_1$ in this case...

Comment: you try $y_1(x+h)$, expand at $x$.

Comment: $\vec{y}_1(x+h) = \vec{y}(x) + \vec{y}'(x)h + O(h^2)$. But now what is x? Because $y_1$ is the approximate solution at $t = t_1$ ($x = t_1$) so I found my method, and subtracting this expression to Taylor expansion of exact solution don't give $O(h^2)$ (the error)...

Comment: You have to show that $y_0 + hf(t_1,y_1) - y(t_1) = O(h^2)$, and you can get $y(t_0) = y(t_1) - hf(t_1,y_1) + O(h^2)$ by Taylor.

Comment: @Yimin Which function you developed to obtain your last Taylor expansion? $y_1(t_1 - h)$? Why this can be done? Thank you.

Comment: expand your function at $t_1$, $y(t_1-h) = y(t_1) - \cdots$

Comment: @Yimin My problem is that approximate solution si $y_1$, not $y$ and is defined only at $t_1$. So $y_1(t_0) \neq y_0$, right?